# EF without implementing UoW or repository would be correct?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, inversion-of-control

I have seen many tutorials that implement with EF a repository pattern and UoW, but I do not see it necessary since DbSet and DbContext already are.
So I decided to simplify it without the implementation but adding services such as that.

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            private IdbContext _dbContextUoW;
            private IClientService _clientService;
            public HomeController (IDbContext dbContextUoW,IClientService clientService){//IoC
                this._dbContextUoW = dbContextUoW;
                this._clientService = clientService;
            }

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                List<Client> clients;
                clients = List<Client>this._clientService(this._dbContextUoW).GetAll();
                //this._dbContextUoW.SaveChanges()

                return View();
            }



        }

        public interface IClientService 
        {
            List<Client> GetAll();
        }
        public class ClientService: IClientService
        {
            private IdbContextUoW _dbContextUoW;
            public ClientService(IDbContext dbContextUoW){
                this._dbContextUoW = dbContextUoW;
            }
            public List<Client> GetAll(){
                return ...
            }
        }
```

Is this implementation correct? am'I on the right track?

**Edit:**
I have finally decided to do the following, I do not know if it is a good solution but to me it seems that yes, creating a generic repository for each service. My serice will have basics CRUD operations(repository) + logic operations(service)

```
 public abstract class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T>
          where T : EntityBase
    {
        protected IContext _entities;
        protected readonly IDbSet<T> _dbset;

        public GenericRepository(IContext context)
        {
            _entities = context;
            _dbset = context.Set<T>();
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
           ...
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> FindBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            ...
        }

        public virtual T Add(T entity)
        {
            ...
        }

        public virtual T Delete(T entity)
        {
            ...
        }

        public virtual void Edit(T entity)
        {
           ...
        }

        public virtual void Save()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
 public class ClienteService : GenericRepository<Cliente>
    {
        IContext _context;
        public ClienteService(IContext context)
            :base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public Cliente GetById(int Id)
        {
            return _dbset.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you're passing in the service, why also pass in the context too? Let DI inject that into the service. Also, yes, this is a perfectly reasonable way to do this.

Comment: I wouldn't want to pass a database context into the controllers, I'd keep th e DB stuff in your data and service layers.    +1 to DavidG for dependency injection, it shines here with something like AutoFac (and I am sure many others) handling the injection for you as part of the Http Request/Response cycle.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it's better to have a unique dbcontext and not create an instance for each service. And so finally make a saveChanges() of that one instance. Or is there a better way?

Comment: Create as many contexts as you like, but never a singleton across your app as they really don't like being accessed concurrently.

Comment: @JHolmer "I wouldn't want to pass a database context into the controllers " Why is the reason? Sorry I'm new.

Comment: You definitely don't want a DB context for each service, you want to share it across your services.  Think of it as your DbConnection & DbTransaction.  I would just create an object that encapsulates the IDbContext for ease of unit testing and separation.  Again, DI shines for that, you add the DB context to your constructor and the DI framework passes the appropriate IDbContext to you in your constructor.

Comment: So each saveChanges() and Dispose must be done for each service? 
Thanks to everyone it is very helpful. Do JHolmer have some example of what you say?

Comment: @DavidG then your solution is delete IDbContext dbContextUoW from controller and pass it to service with IoC (creating one instence per service)?

Comment: Not quite, your IoC container can inject into the service yes, but it could inject the same context - that depends on how you've set it up. For example, in an ASP context, you likely want your context to be per request.

Comment: Also, if using dependency injection, you should not be disposing manually. The DI container owns the instance and should therefore be responsible for also instantiating it and disposing it.

Comment: @Chris Pratt Thanks! I delete it right now

Comment: @Chris Pratt I saw a comment from you that you say; "I usually have just one service per database or access method..." And I would like to do the same but I do not know where to start.

Comment: See my series of posts here: http://cpratt.co/truly-generic-repository/. I call it a "repository" mostly as a contradiction to how devs generally implement repositories. Call it a "service" or whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

You want a dbcontext per request/response.

So create a property on in global.asax for the CurrentContext.

```
    public static YourDbContext CurrentContext
    {
        get { return (YourDbContext) HttpContext.Current.Items[Sessionkey]; }
        private set { HttpContext.Current.Items[Sessionkey] = value; }
    }
```

In application_beginrequest you want to instantiate your dbcontext and store it in the HttpContext

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest() { CurrentContext = new YourDbContext(); }

    protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
        if (CurrentContext != null)
            CurrentContext.Dispose();
    }
```

Then you can wire up your IoC container.  This is castle windsor

```
public class SessionInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container
            .Register(Component.For<YourDbContext>().UsingFactoryMethod(() => MvcApplication.CurrentContext)
                .LifeStyle
                .PerWebRequest);
    }
}
```

I also create a Transaction attribute that handles the creating a committing the transaction.  This attribute can then be applied to the controller method.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CastleWindsor, but this seems overly contrived. Is there no way to bind to self without tying into `HttpContext.Items`? For example, in Ninject, you'd simply do: `kernel.Bind<YourDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope()` and call it a day.

Comment: Tying to HttpContext.Current ensures that the user get's their dbcontext item and not someone else's.  I haven't really looked into doing it another way because this works for me.  And they don't have to use an installer.  windsor just automatically scans for IWindsorInstaller and executes the install method.  You could just put the registration code in global.asax

Comment: That condition is handled by the fact that it's in request scope. The request will always be for one particular user.

Comment: i was thinking that i was re-reading the code.  i'd have to test it out.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought has been that your domain service looks like a repository. A `GetAll()` method (which from my point of view is harmful) isn't the kind of method you want to find in the service layer, which usually has more complex ones to implement actual domain operations (business operations in other paradigms).

If you're going to end up with same methods as a repository messed with more convenient service methods, probably you should go back to the absolutely abstract approach. In order to avoid messing up too much things, you can implement extra methods as *extension methods* to a particular `IDbSet<T>` (i.e. `IDbSet<Client>`, `IDbSet<Product>`, `IDbSet<Whatever>`...). That is, they'll be callable as part of the regular `IDbSet<T>` and you focus your domain services on what they are really mean to do based on their responsibility.

A sample extension method as I've suggested you on the previous paragraph would look as follows:

```
public static IImmutableList<SupportRequest> GetSupportRequestsByClientId(this IDbSet<SupportRequest> dbSet, Guid clientId)
{
      // Do stuff here
      return ...;
}
```

About the thing of not implementing full abstractions of *repository* and *unit of work patterns*, I would find this *ok* if you're dealing with a small project and a limited bucket on which you don't need to think in a long-term basis or you can't ever hope that you'll own the resources to implement an unit testing suite and you need to stay with some integration tests.

Another drawback of getting too coupled to specific unit of work or repository-ish implementations like ones provided by Entity Framework is that Microsoft might evolve it producing breaking changes that can completely destroy your solution. **Obviously, you'll also find other well-known issues like not being able to consume NoSQL data sources and having a hard time to implement unit tests**.

In summary, if you're going to implement a small project, there should be no hassle on going with your proposed approach...

Comment: What do you mean an abstract approach, how would you do it?

Comment: @user2742460 The abstract approach is defining actual unit of work/repository interfaces instead of avoiding them.

Answer (score -1):

the repository partern is better, because your service will rely in a interface and not in implementation.

if you want to use DbConnection with sql you can have a implementation using DbConnection.

if you want to have mongodb repository you can have a implementation using it.

another benefit you separate better the responsibilities using repository pattern.

Comment: My service now depends on an interface, right?

Comment: "the repository partern is better" - please explain this, because many people believe this not to be the case...

Comment: Indeed. I'd argue the opposite, in fact: the repository pattern is *worse*.

Comment: with repository pattern is more easy to make unit tests. Using a IDBContext interface and expose some method of DbContext you will face two problems:  how do you implement it with another kind of repository ? Another problem, to mock the IDbContext interface to make unit test won't be easy.